# How install xfce >= 4.10 from backports repository in debian

Tags: xfce, debian

I am working in Debian 7 64bits with xfce 4.8

[image]

But in backports repository I found xfce 4.10.1

[image]

and I added this line in my sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

but when I upgrade I do not see that can be updated.

[image]

Then, how I can upgrade xfce 4.8 to 4.10 cleanly with backports? without tricks like adding repo of debian 8 testing or others.

Greetings.

Comment: Can you run `apt-cache policy xfce4`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 yes, and the output is here: http://cdn.imghack.se/images/ab7bfa21709acd980c5ca730cabc65fa.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of the deb file there doesn't mean that the file can be used for all releases. The files there are used by everything from `squeeze` to `experimental`. In this case, in `wheezy-backports`, the only `xfce4`-related package is `xfce4-weather-plugin`, where version 0.8.3 was backported to `wheezy`.

For you to get XFCE 4.10, you will have to use another repo.

Answer (score 3):

Add the Mepis Repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ([*Mepis*](http://www.mepis.org/) is based on Debian Stable):

```
deb http://main.mepis-deb.org/mepiscr/xfce/ xfce-4.10 main
```

Run `aptitude update`

Import the repo key & install the backport:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 81E77EAF14E225A0
gpg --armor --export 14E225A0 | apt-key add -
apt-get -t xfce-4.10 install xfce4
```

[image: Debian Wheezy 64 bit with backported XFCE 4.10]

The [Mepis Community Repo](http://main.mepis-deb.org/M12packages.html) also builds for both 32 & 64 bit:

```
deb http://main.mepis-deb.org/mepiscr/repo/ mepis12cr main non-free
```

With this method you can still **keep** `sysvinit` & avoid `systemd`.

To subsequently **apply updates to xfce 4.10** you need to:

`aptitude update && aptitude upgrade`

Comment: Don't forget to `apt-get update` after adding the new repo.